# Objective C: How to disable user interaction to all of tab bars except one?

Tags: objective-c, ios, tabbar, user-interaction

As what the title suggests, I would like to be able to lock all my tab bars except for one. And only after the user completes an action will I enable all the rest of the tab bars. How can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but according to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), you can return NO from the `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` delegate.

[UPDATE] I just tried that out of curiosity - it seems to work fine. Create a new project from the "Tab bar application" template and then go to the `-viewDidLoad` of your FirstViewController. Add this line:

```
[self.tabBarController setDelegate:self];
```

and then implement the delegate method:

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (userHasCompletedAction) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Don't forget to conform to `<UITabBarControllerDelegate>` in your .h file!

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for your response :) Can I check if you know how I can select which tabs to disable? I need to disable all but one tab. In this method, I am not sure if you can specify that?

Comment: @Zhen you have both the tabBarController and the viewController as arguments, so based on your code you can select the desired ones. Check the properties of these classes, for example you could use 'selectedIndex'.

Answer (score 4):

You have to implement this method

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController1 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    if ([tabBarController1 selectedIndex]==0) { 
        UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [[[[self tabBarController]tabBar]items] objectAtIndex:1];
        [tabBarItem setEnabled:FALSE];

    } 
}
```

You have to do something like this for disabling your required tabbar items.

Answer (score 0):

The method `tabBar:didSelectItem:` in `UITabBarDelegate` could help.